Change the class display after selecting a card with a date in Rails
I'm developing an application for a horsemanship school so they can organize their classes and see who booked a class and whatnot!
In the display of all the classes, I've created  to help users choose the day they want to see and then display the classes for the set day.
However, I'm not sure how to accomplish this.
I used stimulus javascript to select a card, however it always chooses the same card, no matter where I click. I've seen some sugestions to use DatePicker, but that only confuses me more.
So I would like to ask you guys some suggestions. Here is my current code:
This is my card partial that I render on the index page:
<div class="d-flex justify-content-start overflow-banner" data-controller="book-class">
  <% Date.today.all_month.to_a.each do |day| %>
    <div
      class="border-div card d-flex justify-content-center col-2 date-banner-card mx-3"
    >
      <div
        class="d-flex flex-column card-body justify-content-center align-items-center"
        data-action="click->book-class#dataSelected"
        data-book-class-target="card"
      >
        <h2>
          <%= day.strftime("%d") %>
        </h2>
        <p>
          <%= day.strftime("%b") %>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

And this is my book-class controller right now. Disclaimer this is just to see if I'm connected and to see if I can get colors to change when selected
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="book-class"
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["toggle", "card"]

  connect() {
    console.log("You're connected")
    console.log(this.cardTarget)
  }

  booked() {
    console.log("you're booked")
  }

  dataSelected() {
    console.log("Selected")
    this.cardTarget.classList.toggle("background-change")
  }
}```


For this case it's better to get your target from event:
dataSelected(event) {
  event.currentTarget.classList.toggle("background-change")
}

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

You can also turn on debug mode which does some useful logging for you:
// app/javascript/controllers/application.js

import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

const application = Application.start()

// Configure Stimulus development experience
application.debug = true                      // <= here
window.Stimulus   = application

export { application }


The day can be used as the argument to your dataSelected(day) function. It must coincide with the id of the target html elemen.
